# EclipseLink disable change tracking per query

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink, change-tracking

We currently experience severe slowdowns in our application due to change tracking in EclipseLink. The problem is home-made, we don’t use JPA as it was meant to be.

I would like to know, how I can get cache hits (1st level), but don’t include these entities in change tracking except some condition is met.

```
// not real code, but close if you decompose the layers and inline methods
public void foo(Long customerId, boolean changeName, String newName) {

    /*** check customer valid ***/
    // #1 HOW TO discard from change tracking? – Customer won’t get modified!
    Customer customer = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerId); 

    // some Business Rules
    // #2 They should be auto discarded from change tracking because #1 is also discarded)
    checkSomething(customer.getAddresses());
    checkSomething(customer.getPhoneNumbers ());
    …

    /*** manipulate customer ***/
    // somewhere else in different classes/methods …
    if(changeName) {
        // #3 HOW TO get Cache hit (1st level) - it was read in #1
        // newName should be persisted
        customer = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerId); 
        customer.setName(newName);
    }
}
```

It would be ok to use EclipseLink API for #1 and #2

I would prefer hints.

EclipseLink 2.4.2

2nd level cache: disabled

ChangeTrackingType: DEFERRED

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [read-only](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_read_only.htm) query hint, which can be passed as a property to find or to queries, and see [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints) for more on hints.  The read-only hint should return the instance from the shared 2nd level cache, which should not be modified.  As it is not added to the 1st level EntityManager cache, any other reads without the hint will build/return the managed instance.

The documentation states this works for nontransactional read operations, so I'm not sure how it will work if the EntityManager is using a transactional connection for reads, as it will not use the shared cache for reads through a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately we don't use a 2nd level cache (session cache).
Using the read-only hint prevents making changes to these entities in step #3 - so this doesn't work either.

Comment: You will have to look into copying your entity then after the initial find operation